# How do I use a text file passed in as an argument from the command line in C?

Tags: c, buffer, command-line-arguments, fgets

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to use a text file that is passed in as a command line argument.  I simply dont know to get the file text into my program to be used.  My code looks something like this....

```
    char buffer[80];
    int i;
    int lineCount = 0;

    fgets(buffer, 80, stdin);  //get the first line

    while (buffer != NULL) {  
        // do some stuff
    }//end fgets while
```

This is for a homework assignment and I know my teacher is going to run the program with the following command:

```
    username@mylunixbox$ ./a.out <data1> output1
```

data1 is the text file I am trying to use.

Comment: What is the output1 needed for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (fp == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n",
                    argv[0], argv[i]);
            rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else
        {
            char line[4096];
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
                ...do stuff with the line read from the file...
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan!  This helps a lot.

Comment: Note that many commands read from standard input if there are no command line arguments (think `cat`, `sort`, ...).  If that's the paradigm you want to use, then write a function that is given an open file pointer and a file name, and call that when you've established that the file was opened successfully.  If no arguments were given, you can then call the same function with `stdin` and a name such as `"(standard input)"` to get the same effect as using a command line argument.  You do much the same if an argument is `-` (a single dash); this conventionally means 'read standard input').

Comment: With your command line design, you seem to want to specify the output file on the command line. Consider the merits of (a) writing to standard output and letting the shell redirect to the named file; (b) using `-o outputfile` option to specify the output. You'd use the [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) function (or its GNU counterparts) to process the command line options; you can search for how to use it on SO. (Incidentally, the function that calls `fopen()` should usually be the one that calls `fclose()`; your service function reads to EOF.)

Answer (score 1):

Use argv[1]. That will give you the file name, then you can use fopen() and use file operations to read the contents from the file.

Comment: Jonathan provided you the full code below. I was recommending the same thing.